# Auth to twitter with login/password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm currently using OAuth to authenticate people with their twitter (twitter gems) acount in my application. The problem is that for people who aren't connected or who have various accounts.

So that's my question, is that possible, to ask user their login/password to link their twitter account on my application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no longer possible to connect to Twitter's API using Twitter credentials.  Twitter's public stance on this is that you should -never- provide your Twitter credentials to anyone else, ever.  This is part of their rationale for implementing OAuth.

Even if you had the user's Twitter password, you couldn't validate that it was actually their password, nor could you access their Twitter account with it through the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look into devise and omniauth. I've gotten it to work this way. Omniauth also allows to link to several accounts. Be it, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Comment: Actually I already have an auth method and I'm using OAuth to login with twitter but i'd like that people could enter their twitter name / password to get their account linked insted of being redirected to Twitter (because of people with multi-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's entirely possible to ask users for their Twitter login/password on your application.  It's a very bad practice though, as OAuth avoids the need for client applications to ever touch a users credentials.  I suggest setting up an authentication/authorization system that maintains a login/password and then allows connecting multiple OAuth accounts via an AuthenticationStrategy model or the like.  Ryan Bates did a few Railscasts on the subject:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2